# Drop down with input text field and a button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, drop-down-menu, textfield

I have a requirement where in a text field and a button in-line and either on click of button or text field the drop down should come up and in addition, the text field should act as a filter. Can any one help in this regard?

The technology can be any of bootstrap, jquery or angularjs.

```
<div style="padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
<form class="bs-example bs-example-form" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
           <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 
                 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                 DropdownMenu 
                 <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
     </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
</div>
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/63fbzgvj/
Also I need the drop down window aligned with the text field not with the button.

Comment: You didn't try anything in your fiddle ? Looking to hire somebody ?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else